# Localizing a point charge from electric field measurements

Tags: electric-fields

I have a point charge at an unknown $\{x_c,y_c,z_c\}$ location in space and an $S_1, S_2, ..., S_i$ set of simultaneous measurements of its electric field strength at known $\{x_i, y_i, z_i\}$ locations that all lie on a plane (that is $z_i = z_j$ for all $i,j$ pairs).

Is it possible to determine the unknown location $\{x_c,y_c,z_c\}$ from this data? If yes, how? If not, what kind of additional information would make it possible?

My hunch is that this is an underdetermined problem but I'm not sure this is indeed the case.

Comment: When you say "the electric field strength", do you mean you have the full electric field _vector_, or just the _magnitude_ of that vector?

Comment: Just the magnitude.

Comment: Do you also know the charge of the point charge?

Comment: That is unknown as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: It is solveable using measurements at four points, but if they all lie in a plane, the solution is ambiguous because of reflection symmetry.

---

You are searching for a point $C$, and you know
$$ |\vec{E}_i| = \frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0} \frac{|q|}{r_i^2} $$
for $i = 1, \dots, n$, where $r_i$ is the distance to $C$ from the point $P_i$ and $q$ is the unknown value of the charge.

First, invert the equation to find
$$ r_i = \sqrt{\frac{|q|}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 |\vec{E}_i|}} \equiv \sqrt{|q|} R_i $$
where you know $R_i$. So, for each of your points, you know the distance to $C$ up to an unknown constant. This is in fact the problem of *multilateration*, which is in fact solved constantly by modern technological devices. For example, mobile phones use the distances to cell towers to find their location and GPS systems use a version of it. Some cursory internet searches gave me a good picture.

Knowing the distance from four points is usually enough. Three spheres generically intersect in two points but four spheres are not guaranteed to all intersect anywhere. Thus, by tuning the value of $q$ - changing the radius of all four spheres by a common factor - you should find only one value of $q$ for which they all intersect. Thus you can solve for both the point $C$ and the charge $q$. A few solution algorithms are listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilateration#Solution_algorithms). I believe that the overall constant $\sqrt{|q|}$ plays a role similar to the a priori unknown [time of transmission (TOT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilateration#Time_of_transmission_(user_clock_offset_or_bias)) in navigation systems.

However, your points are not chosen generically: They all lie on a plane (let's call it the $z = z_P$ plane). By symmetry, it is clear that if one point $C = (x_c, y_c, z_c)$ solves the problem, then its reflection $C' = (x_c, y_c, 2 z_P - z_c)$ in that plane also solves it. So if all your points lie in a plane, you will always have this ambiguity in your solution. If all your points happened to lie on a line, things would get even worse because then you have rotational symmetry around the line.

Comment: Say this setup is not in vacuum but in a biological tissue. That would result in the permittivity term being multiplied with a term expressing relative permittivity (say εr), right?

Comment: @BenjaminMárkus In the simplest case, yes. And then you could still find the location of the particle (but not its charge) in the same way, without knowing εr. I don't know how well it would work in real biological tissue, which may be inhomogeneous (εr varies with the position, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitutive_equation#Electromagnetism).